# How to prevent data value transfer is value equal to 0 in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a stock program. I just want to make the transfer between locations.
For example, FROM A loc. to B Location 5 computers sent but at A location has no computers. I want to show a message on the page: 'There is no device to transfer and. For now, when I transfer it at SQL at A location:-5 computers, and at B location shows 5 computers. I can't prevent it.

I am trying something like this:

```
Create Proc Deneme4
(@StockID    NVARCHAR(100)=NULL,    
     @FROM       NVARCHAR(60)=NULL,
     @TO       NVARCHAR(60)=NULL,
     @CNT           integer= NULL)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @HasExist integer
Select @HasExist = COUNT(1) from STOK_TABLO Where URUNID=@StockID and LOKASYONID=@FROM
IF( @CNT != 0 and @FROM != '' )
BEGIN

UPDATE STOK_TABLO SET ADET=ADET-@CNT WHERE URUNID=@StockID AND LOKASYONID=@FROM
UPDATE STOK_TABLO SET ADET=ADET+@CNT WHERE URUNID=@StockID AND LOKASYONID=@TO
END
ELSE

print 'COUNT is 0 there is no possibility to transfer!'

END
```

```
STOCKID      MODELID    LOCATIONID  COUNT
DS6878HD    DS6878HD    CCR           0
DS6878HD    DS6878HD    CPM           45
```

That is my database also. I want to prevent it if the count is equal to 0. And also I don't want to see a count less than 0.

I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: Just change  where  and add parenthesis : Where (URUNID =`@`StockID and LOKASYONID = `@`FROM and `@`CNT != 0 and `@`FROM != '' )

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to sum the existing value of `ADET` first. Logically you would also want to check if the new value would be *lower* than `0`.

Also

- Do not `PRINT` messages, these are mainly for debugging. Instead use `THROW`
- You probably want a transaction around the whole thing.

  - Therefore, to avoid deadlocks, you want a `UPDLOCK` locking hint on the `SELECT`
  - You also want `SET XACT_ABORT ON` to ensure transactions are cleaned up.
- Seems pointless to allow nulls in the parameters

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC Deneme4
  @StockID    NVARCHAR(100),    
  @FROM       NVARCHAR(60),
  @TO         NVARCHAR(60),
  @CNT        integer
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

IF( ISNULL(
    (
    SELECT SUM(ADET)
    FROM STOK_TABLO WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE URUNID = @StockID
      AND LOKASYONID = @FROM
    ), 0) - @CNT < 0
)
BEGIN
    THROW 50001, N'COUNT is too low, not possible to transfer!', 0;
END;

UPDATE STOK_TABLO
SET ADET += CASE WHEN LOKASYONID = @FROM THEN @CNT ELSE -@CNT END
WHERE URUNID = @StockID
  AND LOKASYONID IN (@FROM, @TO);

IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 2
    THROW 50002, N'Less than 2 rows affected!', 0;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My english is not good but anyway you understood me. I will try it. I tried many ways to resolve it but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer. Thank you for your answer.